# Relation between characteristic polynomial of the matrices $A$ and $f(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix and let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Show that if $$\Delta_A=(x-c_1)^{d_1}\cdots (x-c_r)^{d_r}$$ then $$\Delta_{f(A)}=(x-f(c_1))^{d_1}\cdots (x-f(c_r))^{d_r}$$

My attempt:

So far, I have been able to show that if  $c_i$ is eigenvalue of $A$, then $f(c_i)$ is eigenvalue of $f(A)$:

Suppose $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Then there exists $v$ s.t. $Av=cvI$. Now since $f$ is over $\mathbb{C}[x]$ it can be written as $f(x)=k(x-x_1)...(x-x_m)$. It is sufficient to show that $f(A)v=f(c)vI$. Indeed, $$f(A)v=k(A-x_1I)...(A-x_mI)v=$$
$$=k(A-x_1I)...(Av-x_mvI)=$$
$$=k(A-x_1I)...(cvI-x_mvI)=$$
$$=k(A-x_1I)...v(cI-x_mI)=$$
$$\vdots$$
$$=k(cI-x_1I)...(cI-x_mI)v=$$
$$=f(c)Iv$$
Now I'm stuck with showing the equality of powers. I know that in the case of minimal polynomial the powers represent the dimensions of eigenspaces, but I have no idea about the roles of $d_1...d_r$ in this case.

Comment: Something that might help you: since A is a complex matrix it diagonalizes, so there exist an invertible matrix P and a diagonal matrix D such that A=PDP⁻¹. Then you can check that f(A)=Pf(D)P⁻¹.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt No way. There are non-diagonalizable complex matrices.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry for that. Instead of D diagonal, you may take D the Jordan normal form. I'll elaborate in a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist an invertible matrix $P$ and an a upper triangular matrix $U$ (e.g. the Jordan normal form) such that $A=PUP^{-1}$. Say that $f(x)=k_nx^n+\cdots+k_1x+k_0$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f(A)=f(PUP^{-1}) & = & k_n(PUP^{-1})^n+\cdots+k_1PUP^{-1}+k_0I=\\
 & = & k_nPU^nP^{-1}+\cdots+k_1PUP^{-1}+k_0I =\\
 & = & P(k_nU^n+\cdots+k_1U+k_0I)P^{-1}\\
 & = & Pf(U)P^{-1}
\end{array}
$$
Hence $f(A)-xI=Pf(U)P^{-1}-xI=P(f(U)-xI)P^{-1}$, from where it follows that 
$$\Delta_{f(A)}=\det(f(A)-xI)=\det(P)\det(f(U)-xI)\det(P^{-1})=\det(f(U)-xI).$$

The diagonal of $U$ contains the eigenvalues of $A$ and $U$ is upper triangular, so the diagonal of $f(U)$ contains the images under $f$ of the eigenvalues of $A$. Finally, since $f(U)-xI$ is also upper triangular, you get the determinant by just multiplying the elements of the diagonal.